# Work-built custom vending machine SQL assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server

At work, we have build a vending machine and i have been asked as a side-project to attempt to create a SQL database for it. It will not be used with the vending machine, but will be used for me to practise as i'm very new to SQL (1 month in).

The vending machine will use a keyfob to touch on. Once that's done, you open up the door and grab what you like. The machine has weight sensors, so whatever you take will be added to your fob amount.

Below is what i have produced. I am currently only creating the tables. Please send me your constructive critisism and corrections as it will help me greatly!

```
CREATE TABLE Vender (
    Name varchar (50),
    Description varchar (50)
);

CREATE TABLE Bay (
    StockItem uniqueidentifier,
    Channel integer
);

CREATE TABLE Users (
    NameFirst varchar (50),
    NameLast varchar (50),
    Title varchar (50),
    FobID uniqueidentifier,
    Credential_TakeStock integer,
    Credential_Addstock integer,
    Credential_Admin integer
);

CREATE TABLE Reasons (
    Name uniqueidentifier
);

CREATE TABLE Machine (
    Name uniqueidentifier
);

CREATE TABLE StockItems (
    Code integer,
    Description varchar (50),
    Vendor varchar (50),
    LeadTime time,
    QtyCurrent integer,
    QtyMax integer,
    QtyMin integer,
    QtyCritical integer,
    WeightInGrams integer,
    Bay ???
);

CREATE TABLE Purchase (
    DateTime datetime,
    UserName varchar,
    StockItem uniqueidentifier,
    Reason varchar,
    Machine uniqueidentifier,
    Qty integer,
    DepletedItemReturned bit
);
```

One thing to also mention is i'm not sure of the data value for **Bay** in **StockItems**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Purchase.Reason` should be a `uniqueidentifier`, assumning it links to the `Reasons` table?

Comment: Ah yeah ofcourse. Thank you!

Comment: One of the first things you must do is identify any potential keys - columns (or sets of columns) that are unique and can be used to identify a row. Choose better names. A column named "Name" with a datatype of uniqueidentifier is confusing. Why does a User have a Title? Columns that are flags should be defined as bit or tinyint (depending on the domain). Do not develop the lazy habit of defining variable length strings without a length. "Reason varchar" is the same as "Reason varchar(1)" - that won't work. Surely you will have fobs in stock that are not assigned to anyone - where are they?

Comment: The Time datatype is not why you think it is. LeadTime will need to be a numeric datatype that represents whatever units (hours, days, etc.) are appropriate. Time has a very limited domain of values.

Comment: A purchase is made with a fob - not a user. Don't confuse the two. Over time, a person will likely have multiple fobs (maybe at the same time - be careful what you assume). Is a purchase for a single item only? You can "grab what you like" so how do you intend to capture that?

Comment: Hi SMor, thank you for your comments. I really appreciate it. I will take what you have said into consideration and try to implement them into my database query. I am really new to this so im sorry that a lot of it is wrong!